# Add product from wishlist to quote in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have problem in wishlist

I need to move products from **wishlist** to **enquiry quote**

```
$url = Mage::getUrl('qquoteadv/index/addItem/');
$actionQuote = "addQuote('".$url."');"
```

i tried above code but its not working

any suggestion for this query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Magento, but I think `addQuote` is function, so it should be

```
$actionQuote = addQuote($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

`qquoteadv` is the name of the Magento Cart2Quote extension, so that url won't work if you don't have it installed.

Also, your url is missing the product id:
`qquoteadv/index/addItem/` should be `qquoteadv/index/addItem/product/123/` for example. And it only add's one product.

You could call this url multiple times using ajax, then the url should be `qquoteadv/index/addItemAjax/product/123/` that way you could add the whole wishlist to the quote.